# Is there any way to encryption password?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I'm trying master-slave replication in MySQL, and I have a question about plain text passwords.

When I created an account on the master server I tried
`select * from mysql.slave_master_info;` and the `user_password` shows in plain text.

I wonder is there a way to encryption password without using SSL?

[image: select * from mysql.slave_master_info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no (at least not without using SO_PEERCRED which is restricted to unix domain sockets - i.e. does not cross network).

And SSL (or more correctly TLS) does not change the stored representation of the token used for authentication. It is used as an authentication mechanism, but the private key plain text still must be available at the end offering the proof. i.e. the TLS private key is no different than a bg password in this context.

You can provide additional protections against exploitation by restricting use of this account to specific addresses (or DNS names). e.g. only allow from localhost and use a ssh tunnel (which would allow you to use SO_PEERCRED but moves the problem to the ssh authentication).

**UPDATE**

After some reflection it occurred to me that one approach to limit scope for compromise would be to use the machine's identity as, at least part of, the authentication token. However, whether this is applicable to your use-case is not clear. Outside of a cloud environment, there isn't really a concept of a definitive machine identity but you could use the serial numbers / hardware configuration information available to the OS. But do beware that this will break if you plugin new hardware and only gives assurances about the confidentiality of the password if the storage is compromised (not if the host is compromised):

```
echo "$BASE_PASSWORD $( lshw )" | md5sum
```

Set the password accordingly on the master and configure a startup script to inject the value into the slave DB when required.

Comment: then how can I protect plain text ? using TLS?

Comment: The client key? With a passphrase is the normal solution (same applies to ssh keys). Or use a HSM. Its really a chicken/egg problem.

Comment: Technically solutions like HashiCorp Vault are designed to (partially) solve this kind of problems. It doesn't hide a password completely, instead it forces you to retrieve a password from the special database each time, and the database could be automatically  "sealed" based on signal, for example, from IDS, so password can not be retrieved anymore without admin intervention. Also such systems provide automatic password rotation. Though, I don't know how to apply this to MySQL replication. If MySQL is capable of running a script and using it's output as the password, this is easily possible.

Comment: This still just moves the problem elsewhere, potentially increasing the attack surface.

Comment: This `lshw` solution is very fragile. Any change in the hardware: memory or storage added or removed (imagine a dead and replaced HDD), USB device plugged in, some firmware configuration change, or even a routine OS update when some device is slightly renamed in the driver (it happens!) and your authentication is broken. If you are going to do like that, better use [`tang`](https://github.com/latchset/tang) (or similar) software which binds server to the network presence.